# In category theory, how to make sense of $(X \times Y) \times Z$ in a way that makes use of the natural projections associated with $X \times Y$?

Tags: category-theory

Define that a binary diagram in a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a functor $2 \rightarrow \mathcal{C},$ where $2$ is the discrete category with two objects.

Now if $X$ and $Y$ are objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$ admitting binary products, we can view $X \times Y$ as an object of a new category $\mathrm{Bin}(\mathcal{C})$ whose objects are the cones to binary diagrams in $\mathcal{C},$ and whose arrows are the usual cone homomorphisms. The problem with this point of view is that $(X \times Y) \times Z$ no longer makes sense, since $Z$ is an object of the category $\mathcal{C},$ while $X \times Y$ is an object of a different category $\mathrm{Bin}(\mathcal{C}).$

Okay that's no big deal, we can just view $X \times Y$ as an object of $\mathcal{C}$ when computing $(X \times Y) \times Z.$ But if we do this, then our computation will necessarily disregard the natural projections that $X \times Y$ comes equipped with.

Is there a sensible way of defining $(X \times Y) \times Z$ such that those natural projections are actually taken into account?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You can just, er... *not* do that, and think of $X \times Y$ as an object in $C$ (together with projection maps to $X$ and $Y$) in the usual way. As for the title question, $X \times Y \times Z$ (no parentheses) is the limit of the obvious diagram $3 \to C$.

Comment: I mean, you could just as well say "we can view $X$ as an object of the slice category over $X$, but the problem with this point of view is that $X \times Y$ no longer makes sense." Okay, so *don't* view $X$ that way for the purpose of defining $X \times Y$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I'm just a little concerned that the transition from $X \times Y$ as an object of $\mathrm{Bin}(\mathcal{C})$ to $X \times Y$ as an object of $\mathcal{C}$ throws away a lot of useful information, namely the projections maps.

Comment: But we _aren't_ throwing away that information: it's just not being considered for the purpose of defining $(X \times Y) \times Z$. We will need it again if we wish to prove that $(X \times Y) \times Z \cong X \times (Y \times Z)$. Less diplomatically: stop making such a huge fuss about notation!

Comment: @ZhenLin, hehe sorry. Our opinions about notation are more or less diametrically opposed, it would seem. :-) *Edit.* Anyway, I asked this question because I'm guessing there's some actual math lurking here, not just because of notation.

Comment: Well, it appears to me and others that this question is purely about notation. There is a time and place to be pedantic about notation, but communicating with humans is not one.

Comment: @ZhenLin, if I can find a way to edit the question to make it clear that its not about notation, then I will. Take another look at the last paragraph of the question to see the kind of thing I'm looking for. (I think you will agree it is not purely notational).

Comment: The question in the last paragraph is too general. The situation you have here is that you have a category of diagrams in $\mathcal{C}$, so the product of a diagram and an object can be defined componentwise.

Comment: @ZhenLin, could you elaborate a bit? I think we want $(X \times Y) \times Z$ to correspond in some sense to a diagram of shape $P \rightarrow X \times Y, P \rightarrow Z, X \times Y \rightarrow X, X \times Y \rightarrow Y,$ if that makes any sense.

Comment: Hence, things such our ol' and reliable $\mathbb{R}^3$ *shouldn't* in fact exist, is that it?

Comment: @user18921 That's yet _another_ diagram shape. But note that all that data is already present: we get $X \times Y \to X$ and $X \times Y \to Y$ from the definition of $X \times Y$, and we also get $(X \times Y) \times Z \to X \times Y$ and $(X \times Y) \times Z \to Z$ from the definition of $(X \times Y) \times Z$. So just concatenate the two lots of data. If you're asking whether this fits into the general definition of limit, then the answer is _no_.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan, I made an edit that hopefully clarifies the question. There's also a tentative answer posted that should indicate the kind of things I'm looking for.

Comment: @ZhenLin, I made an edit that hopefully clarifies the question. There's also a tentative answer posted that should indicate the kind of things I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking you are right: $X \times Y$ is not just an object of $C$, but rather it is an object $P$ which comes equipped with two projection morphisms to $X$ resp. $Y$:

$X \times Y = (X \longleftarrow P \longrightarrow Y)$

But it is a common abuse of notation to simply write $P=X \times Y$. Then, of course, $(X \times Y) \times Z$ makes sense (and is isomorphic to $X \times Y \times Z$). If you are not happy with this abuse of notation, you should write $P \times Z$.

Comment: Martin I just edited the question; unfortunately, that makes this answer a little tangential. I feel kind of bad about this, so I gave you a +1 and I'll eventually select this as my accepted answer, as my way of saying sorry. Hope there are no hard feelings.

Comment: I don't care for reputation points. Please select the answer which helped you most and has answered your actual question.

Comment: Ah thanks. Sorry for the poorly worded original question, I'll try to conceptualize questions better in future.

Comment: No problem. The new version of the question is very clear. But I think that you have answered this by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I'm feeling that its pretty much answered, especially in light of your comment thereunder.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea I just had. I'll post it here for critique (but please be gentle!)

We can generalize the notion of a binary product of objects to the notion of a binary product of diagrams.

First, we need the concept of a "disjoint union" of two diagrams. If $\mathcal{C}$ is a category and $D,D'$ are diagrams $J,J' \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$, write $D \boxplus D'$ for the diagram whose shape is the "disjoint union" of $J$ and $J',$ and which agrees with $D$ on the $J$ portion and which agrees with $D'$ on the $J'$ portion. Then we can define that $$D \times D' = \mathrm{lim}(D \boxplus D')$$

so long as the limit exists.

Importantly, the limit needs to be understood as a **cone**, and not just an object of $\mathcal{C}.$ So $D \times D'$ is a cone, if it exists.

Now every cone $K$ induces a diagram in a natural way (include the limit object and the natural projections). Lets denote this $\delta(K).$

Thus, if $D_0,D_1$ and $D_2$ are diagrams, we can interpret $(D_0 \times D_1) \times D_2$ as shorthand for $\delta(D_0 \times D_1) \times D_2.$

Finally, if $X$ is an object of $\mathcal{C},$ lets write $\{X\}$ for the corresponding diagram with shape $1.$ Under these definitions, we can interpret the left hand side of the following equation as shorthand for the right hand side.

$$(X \times Y) \times Z = \delta(\{X\} \times \{Y\}) \times \{Z\}$$

So that's the idea, I don't know if it really goes anywhere, but comments and suggestions would be most welcome.

One interesting observation is that if we redefine $\delta$ such that $\delta(K)$ is still the diagram associated with the cone $K$, but this time **not** including the limit object or the natural projections, then we essentially get the usual interpretation of $(X \times Y) \times Z.$

Comment: That's OK. In fact, in my impression, this is how experienced category theorists think about something like $(X \times Y) \times Z$. But we are lazy when it comes to notations ...

Answer (score 2):

> Okay that's no big deal, we can just view $X \times Y$ as an object of $\mathcal{C}$ when computing $(X \times Y) \times Z.$ But if we do this, then our computation will necessarily disregard the natural projections that $X \times Y$ comes equipped with.

Why? $(X \times Y) \times Z$ itself comes with two natural projections, a projection to $X \times Y$ and a projection to $Z$. Once you have the projection to $X \times Y$, you can compose it with the projections $X \times Y \to X, X \times Y \to Y$ and get three projections to $X, Y, Z$, and then $(X \times Y) \times Z$ together with these three projections satisfies the correct universal property.

Another way of saying this is that, if you take the perspective that $X \times Y$ is a representing object for the functor $\text{Hom}(-, X) \times \text{Hom}(-, Y)$, then $(X \times Y) \times Z$ is a representing object for the functor

$$\text{Hom}(-, X \times Y) \times \text{Hom}(-, Z)$$

which is in turn naturally isomorphic to

$$\text{Hom}(-, X) \times \text{Hom}(-, Y) \times \text{Hom}(-, Z)$$

as expected.

Comment: I guess it depends what you want to do with the concepts. Given the entity $(X \times Y) \times Z$ only, there is no way to obtain the natural projection $f : (X \times Y) \times Z \rightarrow X.$ I am concerned that this may limit the usefulness and/or naturalness of the construction, although I cannot think of an explicit example where it might be a problem.

Comment: If the reason that the projection $f : (X \times Y) \times Z \rightarrow X$ cannot be obtained from $(X \times Y) \times Z$ alone isn't clear, let me know and I will try to clarify. Its a bit of a subtle issue.

Comment: @user: I disagree. When you write $X \times Y$ you're talking about an object equipped with projection maps to $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: To be explicit we can write $U(X \times Y)$ to denote $X \times Y$ viewed as an object of $\mathcal{C}.$ Then $(X \times Y) \times Z$ is shorthand for $U(X \times Y) \times Z$, and the latter expression is clearly independent of any additional structure possessed by $X \times Y$. Do you not agree?

Comment: @user: I disagree. When I write $(X \times Y) \times Z$ I'm keeping in mind that there's extra data attached to $X \times Y$. This seems like by far the most sensible convention if you're going to pick a convention.

Comment: Yes, that could work. But, any idea how to formalize it? I think we'd need to distinguish between the elements of a (possibly large) set $S$ versus the 'structured elements' of $S$, the latter being ordered pairs $(s,D)$ where $s \in S$ and $D$ is some additional data. Since every $s \in S$ can be identified with the corresponding structured element with empty data, every element is "morally" a structured element. So if we can define $X \times Y$ for arbitrary structured objects of a category, that might work.

Comment: Anyway, let me know if you have any thoughts on the matter.